# Haskells stack or interact are adding characters

Tags: haskell

I'm doing my first steps using Haskell. I created a project using `stack` and changed the Main.hs into

```
module Main where

my_fkt :: String -> String
my_fkt input = show (length input)

main :: IO ()
main = interact my_fkt
```

I build the project via `stack build`, run it via `stack exec firststeps-exe`, enter "abcd" and finish input via `<CTRL>-D`. In the console I now see

```
abcd4%
```

The `%`is inverted. If I use a text file containing the "abcd" (without line break) and execute `more sample.txt | stack exec firststeps-exe` I see

```
abcd5%
```

Why do I get one additional character in the second case and what is the inverted percentage sign?

Comment: I believe this is a feature of your shell; a character is added that indicates end-of-output so that the next prompt can be printed at the beginning of the line (in bash you would see your prompt printed in place of the "%"

Comment: Try `show (length input) ++ "\n"` to add a newline at the end. Still, note that the `interact` approach quickly becomes hard. Unless the problem is very simple like this one, I'd not recommend `interact`.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the definition of interact uses `putStr` instead of `putStrLn`.

You can take a look at the source code [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/src/System.IO.html#interact).

> ```
> interact        ::  (String -> String) -> IO ()
> interact f      =   do s <- getContents
>                        putStr (f s)
> ```

To remedy your issue I would go on and create a similar function

```
interact' :: (String -> String) -> IO ()
interact' f = do s <- getContents
                putStrLn (f s)
```

or if you like to mix it up and write a bit terser code

```
interact' f = putStrLn =<< (f <$> getContents)
```

I don't know what the `%` is or why it is showing up, my guess would be that it is the escaped `CTRL-D`.

With regards to your second question about the additional "non-existing" character, I am also not sure, but here my guess would be that this is the `\EOF`.

Btw. you can always check using `more testinput | wc -c` it should yield the same result as your haskell program.

Comment: One could also write `interact' f = interact ((++"\n") . f)`